# Creating a new database (.mdb) with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, ms-jet-ace

How can I create a empty .mdb file? I'm using ADO.NET and C#. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy a pre-existing .mdb file is the best way.

The same is true for most of the other filebased database formats that ADO.NET can connect to, such as Excel files.  Since a file based database system is using the filesystem as it's host and API for communication with the outside world (as opposed to say MSSQL which communicates using TCP-IP), it quite natural to use System.IO for actions that in say MS-SQL would be done with T-SQL or system stored procedures or a data specific API that targets thoses (say SMO in SQL server's case).

`COPY model.mdb newdb.mdb`  is the create DB command

`DEL newdb.mdb is the drop` DB command, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a ".NET native" way to do it, but you still can wrap ADOX:

```
using ADOX;  // add a COM reference to "Microsoft ADO Ext. x.x for DDL and Security" 

static void CreateMdb(string fileNameWithPath)
{
  ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
  string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5";
  cat.Create(String.Format(connstr, fileNameWithPath));
  cat = null;
}
```

Comment: Are you on 64 bit? From what I find in Google this may be causing it. (see: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=47427)